# Trying to retrieve all payments data via Stripe API including metadata

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Trying to retrieve all payments and associated data including metadata for payments made in prior calendar month via Stripe API using PHP.

This approach does not include all payments:

```
// Set your Stripe API key
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$start = strtotime("first day of previous month");
$end = strtotime("last day of previous month");
$payments = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::all([
    'created' => [
        'gte' => $start,
        'lte' => $end,
    ],
    'limit' => 100,
]);
```

While this seems to include all payments, but NOT the metadata:

```
// Set your Stripe API key
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$start = strtotime("first day of previous month");
$end = strtotime("last day of previous month");
$transactions = \Stripe\BalanceTransaction::all([
  'created' => [
      'gte' => $start,
      'lte' => $end,
  ],
  'limit' => 100,
  ]);
```

Is there a call that will include all payments with metadata? or can I use the second block of code and add some call to get additional details, including metadata, for each individual transaction, perhaps using the id returned in the BalanceTransaction example?

Answer (score 0):

If the metadata is set on PaymentIntent objects. You should use the List All PaymentIntents [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/list) instead to retrieve the PaymentIntents and access their metadata.

Comment: List All PaymentIntents does not list all payments. It only lists about 30%.

Comment: It does list all. Make sure you're properly paginating the results so you get everything. https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto?lang=php